# Find position of object in postgres jsonb array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have an array of objects that looks like this within the jsonb `value` column of a table:

```
"west": [
  {"id": "aa92f346-7a93-4443-949b-4eab0badd983", "version": 1},
  {"id": "cd92e346-6b04-3456-050a-5eeb0bddd027", "version": 3}
]
```

I'm aiming to remove certain objects from this array based on their id and version like so:

```
SELECT value::jsonb #- '{west, 1}' FROM game.settings;
```

However, the `1` should not be hard-coded, but rather should equal the position of the object within the array which matches the id and version I'm looking for (in this case `"id": "cd92e346-6b04-3456-050a-5eeb0bddd027", "version": 3`).

How would I go about determining this array position and passing it into the spot my hard-coded `1` currently holds?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Example data:

```
create temp table settings as
select 
    '{"west": [
      {"id": "aa92f346-7a93-4443-949b-4eab0badd983", "version": 1},
      {"id": "cd92e346-6b04-3456-050a-5eeb0bddd027", "version": 3}
    ]}'::jsonb as value;
```

You can use [`jsonb_array_elements() with ordinality`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to determine the array position of a given element:

```
select elem, position
from settings, jsonb_array_elements(value->'west') with ordinality arr(elem, position)
where elem->>'id' = 'cd92e346-6b04-3456-050a-5eeb0bddd027';

                             elem                             | position 
--------------------------------------------------------------+----------
 {"id": "cd92e346-6b04-3456-050a-5eeb0bddd027", "version": 3} |        2
(1 row)
```

Use `position` to remove the object from the array:

```
select value #- array['west', (position- 1)::text] new_value
from settings, jsonb_array_elements(value->'west') with ordinality arr(elem, position)
where elem->>'id' = 'cd92e346-6b04-3456-050a-5eeb0bddd027';

                                new_value                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"west": [{"id": "aa92f346-7a93-4443-949b-4eab0badd983", "version": 1}]}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking for the index of that object within the array however.

Comment: I had to read the question inattentively, sorry. I hope the edited answer reflects the real issue now..